# render a HTML template for Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

HTML Code:

```
<form id="add_post">
    <div id="post-add-tag">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="post_tags" name="post_tags" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="add_tag_button" type="submit">Add</button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul id="tags_list"></ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP code that prints this scripts into footer:

```
function post_tag_template(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/template" id="the_template">
        <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="items[]" value="{{= stripHTML(name) }}" />
            {{= stripHTML(name) }}
        </li>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function stripHTML(html)
        {
           var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
           tmp.innerHTML = html;
           return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
function addTag(tag) {
    var form        = $('form#add_post'),
        tags_list   = form.find('ul#tags_list'),
        source      = $('#the_template').html();    

    tags_list.append(source);
}

$(document).on('click', 'form#add_post #add_tag_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    addTag( $('input#post_tags').val() );
});
```

What are my codes do?

My codes print the content of template `#the_template` without replace `#{{= stripHTML(name) }}` with the tag name (The value of input `#post_tags`).

What do I need to do?

I want when I click on `#add_tag_button` get the template content `#the_template` and replace `{{= stripHTML(name) }}` with the tag name (The value of input `#post_tags`).

Comment: What template library are you using?  jQuery doesn't have any sort of built in templating logic, at least in the core afaik

Comment: @Taplar I was using backbone but I decide to remove backbone so I try to make the same thing but with javascript or jquery.

Comment: I would highly suggest sticking with backbone, or mustachejs or handlebarjs to handle the templating logic, or some other templating library.  jQuery isn't intended to do everything, :P

Comment: I totally understand this, But I am sure we can do the same results without the backbone, like get the template content and replace {{= stripHTML(name) }} to the tag name, I tried using jquery replace but i failed :D

Comment: Take a look at mustachejs or handlebarsjs.  You would have to change your syntax slightly, but its probably a better idea to use a library for this rather than writing your own, especially if you are going to be doing this fairly commonly.

Comment: Check nunjucks.js it's the best by far. Twig for js is 2nd best. I'm telling you this after extensive research to find the best template engine 4 js.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function post_tag_template(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/template" id="the_template">
        <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="items[]" value="{{PlainName}}" />
            {{PlainName}}
        </li>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function stripHTML(html)
        {
           var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
           tmp.innerHTML = html;
           return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Javascript code:

```
    function addTag(tag) {
    var form        = $('form#add_post'),
        tags_list   = form.find('ul#tags_list'),
        source      = $('#the_template').html();   

   var search1 = /{{PlainName}}/g;
    tags_list.append(source.replace(search1, stripHTML(name)}
```

Since you have multiple replace elements, you should use Regx.

Comment: Sorry, but it will not be working and you will get many errors.

Comment: Okay, Can I know what is 'name'? how you get the value of that variable?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put quotes --> tags_list.append(source.replace("{{PlainName}}", stripHTML(name)}

Comment: I know that you forget to add quotes but I trying but nothing change, and replace name to 'tag' to get the name of the tag from the function. After I repair your code and trying the jquery replace function doesn't work when I add the tag it adds the tag name as {{PlainName}}

Comment: Okay, try with  /{{PlainName}}/g